# Is it possible to use AWS application load balance with CloudFront distribution and EC2 as target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Hi I would like to use AWS application load balancer and create target group which should point default to my CloudFront distribution and based on the rule it will point to other apps. I could not find the resource to do it. Anyway have done such things.

Our landing page is pointing to the CloudFront distribution(+AWS S3) and we wanted to have with /xyz it should point to our ec2 instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't point to cloudfront from your application load balanacer instead you can create behaviours or behavior groups in cloudfront to point to your load balancer.

Just like

Default (*) -> s3

/xyz  -> application load balancer

Comment: okay now default is working but for /xyz which is pointing to load balancer goes into too many redirect and crashed. It seems I am missing some thing here. 

FYI, My server is running with apache. Do I need to make some changes there.

Comment: No, there are no special changes necessary, but be awart of DNS names and routing. Use the EC ALP DNS Name für /xyz. If your Apache Config redirects HTTP to HTTPS ensure Cloudfront uses https.

Comment: Make sure for loadbalancer configuration you've correct loadbalancer to host port mapping. Like if you've enable ssl with amazon certificate manager on loadbalancer you should map loadbalancer's 443 port to host 80 port, moreover make sure if cloudfront is also following https to  connect to you /xyz behavior group if you are using ssl with loadbalancer else cloudfront behaviour should use http.